# React Library PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I am building a library with React and babel, everything works great except that the VSCode intellisense cannot read the prop types of the component.

I write the components the following way

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
      render(){...}

      static propTypes ={
          propA: PropTypes.string
      }
}
```

and build this way:

```
  "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore __tests__,spec.js,test.js,__snapshots__",
```

my `.babelrc` file is

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "useBuiltIns": "entry" }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", {"loose":true}]
  ]
}
```

is there a way to trigger the intellisense?

Comment: I think there's a plugin for that

Comment: [React Proptypes Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OfHumanBondage.react-proptypes-intellisense)

Comment: does not work....